# How to communicate to a long-running React Chrome Extension via the default_popup modal?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome Extension that overlays a choice `div` over the current web page.

I have spent considerable time studying how to develop a Chrome Extension with React and with regular ways to inject HTML and JS. More React-specific information is needed to put this together.

My goal is to achieve this:

1. Click `default_popup` which reveals some extension settings
2. Toggle overlay ON
3. *A full-screen overlay covers the current webpage*
4. Dismiss the default_popup modal
5. The overlay is still there because the React-based extension is still running
6. Click `default_popup` which reveals the extension settings again
7. Toggle overlay OFF

I have followed every tutorial I can find on Google and dissected every React Chrome Extension I can find in GitHub, and this my question that arises after that.

Can anyone provide an example or describe exactly what needs to be done to achieve the above steps?

> The most important thing I can't find from any tutorials or code spelunking is how do I inject a React App as a Chrome Extension and have it talk to the default_popup modal?

Comment: `the React-based extension is still running` - what do you call `extension` and where exactly does it run? Is it the content script? The background/event page? Because if you think default_popup is running after being closed, you're mistaken. Are you trying to run the react app in the web page via content script?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. How do I call / load / embed / start / maintain the extension so that I can talk to it from the popup modal?

Comment: Here is an example of an extension doing essentially what I want, except I want to provide multiple types of overlays from the popup: https://github.com/chuckhendo/chrome-bootstrap

Comment: You can use a persistent background page or an event page (if your app is fast to load and you can save the state in chrome.storage) P.S. browserAction popup is not a popup modal, it's a separate page.

Comment: I recall it may be possible to run index.html as a background/event page. That's what I need to see. I need to see how to boot up a React extension as an event page or background script and then toggle stuff from the popup page.

Comment: I will try an update my question with more example code, under the assumption that we want to put the React app into an event page and then a) cause it to conditionally change a webpage b) communicate with the popup page. I may end up answering it myself, but the answer to my question needs to exist in a searchable format.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between the popup ( i assume you mean browserAction here) and any open tab the easiest way would be through background script.
So in manifest.json you add

```
"background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

and then in background.js file you can listen to events emitted from contentScript or browserAction scripts with [onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

```
//background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(message){
    // do some actions depending on message object
    // e.g. add or remove overlay with tabs api 
}
```

and send message from your popup with [sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) like this

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "TOGGLE_OVERLAY", toVisible: true})
```

please note: if you want to send messages to [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) you should use [tabs API sendMessage instead](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage)